# Does my program to solve a math equation have any mistakes?

Tags: c#, math, console

I wrote a simple program to solve the math problem:

```
A^2+B^2 = 12
A*B = 9
(A+B)^2 = y
```

My program is looping through each number starting at `0.000000001`, and checking to see if the first equation is true (the second one is always true because I always assign double `B = 9 / A`).

Then it writes the results and pauses. This is taking forever to run since its doing a lot of math, I was wondering if I made any mistakes so I can fix them? Here is  my code:

```
namespace AnnoyingMath1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (double a = 0.00000001; a < 9; a += 0.00000001) {
                double b = 9 / a;
                if (Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2) == 12)
                {
                    if (a * b == 9) // always true because b = 9 / a
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS! a = " + a.ToString() + ", b = " + b.ToString() + ", y = (a+b)^2 = " + (Math.Pow(a + b, 2)).ToString() );
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("fail1 " + a.ToString() + " , " + b.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, its a math problem that i cant seem to solve by hand

Comment: Offtopic: I wouldn't recommend using a computer program to bruteforce a problem like this, because you are unable to do similar questions later on.

Comment: @DMan i already got an answer myself (even though it was wrong) and my friend got an answer too, our answers were for y and niether of us could find a and b, i dont need to be able to solve similar questions later on because im in 8th grade, we didnt even learn this kind of algebra yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It does.

statements such as:

```
if (a * b == 9) // always true because b = 9 / a  WRONG, because you are dealing with floating point
```

are incorrect.

Never directly compare floating point values. Use a delta instead:

```
epsilon = 0.000001
if (Abs(a*b - 9) <= epsilon )
```

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow.

Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: ah ok, thanks, do i have to put it anywhere besides the if statements?

Comment: just when comparing values for equality

Comment: suggest you look at @nightshifted's answer

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check for "close enough" answers, since there's no guarantee you will get a nice round number.  So instead of checking for (VAL) == 12, check for (VAL) > 11.9M && < 12.1M.  Also, why not try some kind of convergence method instead of cycling through every number?

Comment: cant i just use Math.Round()?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned not being able to solve this by hand...

```
y = (a+b)^2
  = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
  = (a^2 + b^2) + 2 * ab
  = 12 + 2 * 9
  = 30
```

Going brute force on an algebra question is never the right method.

(Was going to add this in a comment as I realize SO isn't the place for math homework help, but the formatting goes all wonky.)

Comment: just wondering, on line 2 where does + 2ab come from? because this is what my friend got when he did it by hand

Comment: +1. solution by algebra alone is better than an iterative floating point solution. And becasue it answers the question you really wanted answering and not the one you actually asked.

Comment: How did you get from line 3 to line 4? Brute force is not the way to do it, but neither is randomly assigning values to variables :-)

Comment: i do have two equations, i have to find a and b, i should have specified, not find y. so i have to find what a and b is if both equations are true.

Comment: @pax got the values from OP! they were smushed together in the same line.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see that until I reformatted the question.

Comment: sorry, i should've added the formatting to the math -_-

Comment: @Efe (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 is basic FOIL. if you want a and b, just plug one of the equations into another. now that you have y, it should be trivial.

Comment: @nightshifted oh ok, sorry i didnt look at (a+b)^2 as (a+b)(a+b)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find an answer using that kind of algorithm, even if you use delta while comparison. There is no result within [Real Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) for that equations:

```
A + B = 9
A^2 + B^2 = 12

B = 9 / A
A^2 + (9 / A)^2 = 12
```

After some transformations and T = A^2:

```
T^2 - 12T + 81 = 0

Delta = 144 - 4 * 81 < 0
```

You can go further into [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) to found results with imaginary unit.

Comment: im in 8th grade, so you lost me in the second box, but what your saying is, that its impossible for me to find values for a and b?